# Spring Boot Java .JAR file corrupt in Docker image (via Docker Hub) since using Git LFS

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, git-lfs, dockerhub

**Java .JAR file in Docker image is corrupt since Git LFS**

Since I use Git LFS to upload files to Github, the Docker image created on Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com) contains a corrupt Java .JAR file.

If I disable Git LFS and push the Java .JAR file the Docker Hub, the Docker image works properly.

- I use IntelliJ IDEA
- I setup the Git LFS based on this tutorial: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files

The .JAR is builded with Maven in IntelliJ. The upload to Git LFS via command line in IntelliJ, based on the official tutorial mentioned above, is successfully without errors. If I look at the Giuthub repository I can see the .JAR with the note "Stored on Git LFS" with the correct file-size. Even the build process on Docker Hub is successfully without an error.

The Dockerfile on Docker Hub is:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:18.0.2
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/myapp.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /myapp.jar
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

The build process on Docker Hub is successfully without an error.

I can also download the Docker image to my server and execute the Docker image. Then, the console output of the Docker container is: `Error: Java .JAR file is corrupt`

**UPDATE #1**

I created a support ticket on Github and got a answer from the support:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch. This appears to be [a longstanding issue
> with Dockerhub](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500).
>
> You may want to reach out to them to find out if they intend on adding
> support for LFS.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Fiona

The link she mentioned is: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500

Seems that problems exists for a while and is still not resloved.

**UPDATE #2**

Got an answer from the Docker support

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Docker Support.
>
> Currently Docker Hub does not support Git LFS  :
> https://docker-docs.netlify.app/docker-hub/builds/  Regards,
>
> Docker Support

I checked the link that was provided by the support and found this:

> Currently Docker Hub does not support Git LFS (Large File Storage). If
> you have binaries in your build context that are managed by Git LFS,
> only the pointer file is present in the clone made during the
> automated build, which is not what you want.
>
> Subscribe to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500) tracking this limitation.

The link to the mentioned Github issue on this page is: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500

Sadly, the issue is open since 7 years.

Comment: I feel its problem with build process, problem zeroes down to how jar is built.
I am not sure how your jar build process is setup but I feel you need to look at debug output at that level

also if you say you are uploading files via git lfs, is it rejecting any files while uploading? you should see some debug output

Comment: @swapyonubuntu I build the .JAR with Maven in IntelliJ. The upload to Git LFS via command line in IntelliJ is successfully, without errors. If I look at the Giuthub repository I can see the .JAR with the note "Stored on Git LFS" with the correct file-size. Even the build process on Docker Hub is successfully without an error.

Comment: Since you said jar file is corrupt, Can you try both cases running both jars manually with java -jar, 
if this fails(and jar is corrupt and does not run) means that we can isolate docker build process altogether and focus on jar build process.

Comment: @swapyonubuntu If the JAR file is not on Git's LFS (just normally pushed to Github), then the JAR file is not corrupt and the Docker image is working properly. I updated the thread, got an answer from Github support.